# What is the correct answer for $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{p^2}{(p-3)^2}\right)?$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

What is the correct answer for $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{p^2}{(p-3)^2}\right)?$$
Using partial fraction technique I got the answer as: $\delta(t)+e^{3t}9t+6e^{3t}$ and uing shifting thorem for inverse Laplace I gotthe answer as: $e^{3t}(\delta(t)+6+9t)$.

Comment: The first is correct.

Comment: Why the second one is incorrect?

Comment: That is a bit trickier as I don't live inside your head...there are lots of ways to make something incorrect. How did you get that answer?

Comment: I used shifting theorem to get the second answer, but don't know why it is incorrect. Kindly provide some reasons.

Comment: @user90533 I've noticed that all of your questions are unanswered. You should mark an answer of your questions as the best, i.e., the one that most helped you to comprehend the topic. This is important so that the question will not remain as unanswered.

Comment: @user90533 To do this, just click on ✔ in the answer of your choice, below the upvote/downvote buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The **frequency shift property** of Laplace Transform states that:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:1.1px solid black] {
F(p+a)\iff e^{-at}\cdot f(t)
}
$$
It's implicit in this property that you must apply the inverse Laplace transform to $F(p)$, and then multiply the result by $e^{-at}$.

---

We can use it in the case you've presented, look:

$$
F(p-3)=\frac{p^2}{(p-3)^2}
$$
If $p'=p-3$, then $p=p'+3$. So, we have:
$$
F(p'+3-3)=\frac{(p'+3)^2}{(p'+3-3)^2}\iff F(p')=\frac{(p'+3)^2}{(p')^2} \implies F(p)=\frac{(p+3)^2}{p^2}
$$
Applying the inverse Laplace transform to $F(p)$, we have:
$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[F(p)\right]&=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{(p+3)^2}{p^2}\right]
\\&=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{p^2+6p+9}{p^2}\right]
\\&=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[1+\frac 6 p + \frac{9}{p^2}\right]
\\&=\delta(t)+6+9t=f(t)
\end{alignat}
$$

Using the frequency shift property:
$$
\bbox[5px,border:1.1px solid black] {
\mathscr{L}^{-1}[F(p-3)]=e^{-(-3)t}\cdot f(t)=e^{3t}\cdot[\delta(t)+6+9t]
}
$$
**So, both answers are correct**

---

Having that in mind, we need to prove that $$e^{3t}\delta(t)=\delta(t)$$
**First, it's necessary to make some clarifications:**

> A "delta function" is not really a function, it's what is called a "generalized function", or [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29).  So, when you see people write $\delta(0) = \infty$, this is just a "formality", and a very misleading one at that.  The *only* correct way to think about a delta function is under an integral sign with another ("normal") function $f(x)$:
>   $$
> \int \delta(x)f(x)dx
> $$ 
>   This expression makes perfect sense, and as long as $f(x)$ is "nice enough" (e.g. continuous at 0), it will evaluate to $f(0)$.
>                                                                                                           *<sub>Source: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1732428/302736) answer, given by the user icurays1</sub>*

So, all we need is this definition: 
$$
\bbox[9px,border:1.1px solid black] {
\int f(t)\cdot \delta(t)\,\,dt \triangleq f(0)
}
$$
**The proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
\delta(t)=1\cdot\delta(t) &\implies \int 1\cdot \delta(t)\,\,dt=1
\\ e^{3t}\cdot\delta(t)&\implies \int e^{3t}\cdot\delta(t)\,\,dt=e^{3\cdot\color{red}{0}}=1
\end{align}
$$
So, we can conclude that:
$$
\\ \int\delta(t)\,\,dt=\int e^{3t}\cdot\delta(t)\,\,dt \implies\delta(t)=e^{3t}\delta(t)
$$

---

### One important note:

You should **avoid** interpreting the Dirac Delta Function this way:
$$
\delta(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\infty & x = 0 \\
0 & x\neq 0 
\end{array}\right.
$$

I'll show one example that illustrates why:

**What is $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right]$? And $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(3t)\,\right]$?**

Using the above interpretation, we have:
$$
\begin{alignat}{0}
\delta(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\infty & t = 0 \\
0 & t\neq 0 
\end{array}\right.
&&\delta(3t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\infty & 3t = 0 \\
0 & 3t\neq 0 
\end{array}\right.
= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\infty & t = 0 \\
0 & t\neq 0 
\end{array}\right.
=\delta(t)
\end{alignat}
$$
So, since we have the same "function"... $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right]$ must be equal to $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(3t)\,\right]$, right? **WRONG!**
$$
\begin{alignat}{1}
\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right]&=1 \\
\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(3t)\,\right]&=\frac 1 3
\end{alignat}
$$
But Laplace Transform Uniqueness Theorem states that:

> $$\mathscr{L}[\,f_1\,]\neq\mathscr{L}[\,f_2\,] \iff f_1 \neq f_2$$

(And this theorem is valid for Dirac Delta 'function').

Then:
$$
\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right] \neq \mathscr{L}[\,\delta(3t)\,] \iff \delta(t) \neq \delta(3t)
$$

---

*Note:*

One could argue: "But Dirac Delta 'function' isn't continuous. You have omitted the part of Uniqueness theorem that says that $f_1$ and $f_2$ must be continuous on $[0,∞)$.Then, the theorem is not valid for this case."

My counter argument: Yes, Delta 'function' isn't continuous. But there is a theorem stronger than this one which says that Uniqueness also applies to the Dirac Delta Function. See [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MzlR.png), extracted from [Laplace Transform Lecture Notes - Ante Mimica](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~amimica/lt.pdf) (Suggested by Calvin Khor [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211238/unilateral-laplace-transform-uniqueness-and-dirac-delta-function))

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct as $\delta(t)=e^{3t}\delta(t)$. See the definitions of [delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) and [delta sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaSequence.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct because $\delta(t)=e^{3t}\delta(t).$

$$\delta(t)=\{_{0,\;\;x\neq0}^{+\infty,\;x=0}$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)dt=1$$
Likewise
$$e^{3t}\delta(t)=\{_{0,\;\;x\neq0}^{+\infty,\;x=0}$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{3t}\delta(t)dt=1$$
since $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)\delta(t)dt=f(0)$$
Therefore
$$\delta(t)=e^{3t}\delta(t)$$

Comment: Thank you  for your detailed answer

Comment: hah! didn't even notice that.