# Unilateral Laplace Transform Uniqueness and Dirac Delta "function"

Tags: laplace-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Answering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3211150/302736) question, I've tried to alert the OP about the **misleading definition** of $\delta(t)$ - used in one of the answers - as:

$$
\delta(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\infty & x = 0 \\
0 & x\neq 0 
\end{array}\right.
$$

And gave an example when this definition fails:

> I'll show one example that illustrates why:
>
> **What is $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right]$? And $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(3t)\,\right]$?**
>
> Using the above interpretation, we have:
> $$
> \begin{alignat}{0}
> \delta(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
> \infty & t = 0 \\
> 0 & t\neq 0 
> \end{array}\right.
> &&\delta(3t) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
> \infty & 3t = 0 \\
> 0 & 3t\neq 0 
> \end{array}\right.
> = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
> \infty & t = 0 \\
> 0 & t\neq 0 
> \end{array}\right.
> =\delta(t)
> \end{alignat}
> $$
> So, since we have the same "function"... $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right]$ must be equal to $\mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(3t)\,\right]$, right? **WRONG!**
> $$
> \begin{alignat}{1}
> \mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right]&=1 \\
> \mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(3t)\,\right]&=\frac 1 3
> \end{alignat}
> $$
> But Laplace Transform Uniqueness Theorem states that:
>
> > If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous on $[0,∞)$, then $\mathscr{L}[\,f_1\,]\neq\mathscr{L}[\,f_2\,] \iff f_1 \neq f_2$
>
> Then:
> $$
> \mathscr{L}\left[\,\delta(t)\,\right] \neq \mathscr{L}[\,\delta(3t)\,] \iff \delta(t) \neq \delta(3t)
> $$

---

I argued that $\delta(t)$ must be different of $\delta(3t)$ because of **Laplace Uniqueness Theorem**. But now I realized that my argument **fails**, because Dirac Delta "function" **isn't continuous**. So, my questions are:

- Is this theorem valid for Delta "function", even if it isn't continuous in the traditional sense? If yes, why?
- If no, is there a stronger theorem about uniqueness of Laplace Transform, which allows Dirac Delta "function" to be included?

Comment: There isn't a need to go through Laplace transforms. Scaling of a distribution is defined via extending the identity on test functions $\int f(3x) g(x) dx = \frac13\int f(y)g(y/3) dy$, so $\delta(3x)$ has the action $$ \langle \delta(3x) , \phi(x) \rangle := \langle \delta(y) , \frac13 \phi(y/3) \rangle = \phi(0)/3$$ which makes it clear that they aren't the same

Comment: You're right, but I'm trying to look at it using only Laplace transform and uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Well I don't find this argument convincing because it assumes I know how to interpret $\mathcal L[\delta(3x)]$ without knowing the above basic definition of how to scale a distribution. That said, it seems that Laplace transforms uniquely determine finite measures anyway. (prop 1.8) https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~amimica/lt.pdf

Comment: @CalvinKhor I'll give some context about my question: I've learned Laplace Transform in Electric Circuits class. My teachers defined the Dirac Delta with the mislead definition, and then asked in a test only about Laplace transforms if $\delta(t)=\delta(2t)$. The explanation given in this question was the explanation I could give, given the knowledge I had, and that was the correct answer, according to them. This happened some months ago. I was satisfied with this argument until today, when I realized that it fails.

Comment: That's why I'm "forcing" the Laplace transform way: if they asked the students this question, considering their knowledge about Delta "function" (the misleading definition), then there must be a way to solve it using only the basic theory related to Laplace Transforms and not to distributions.

Comment: I guess that the condition of continuity can be dropped as long as we allow the functions to differ on a null set (e.g. a countable set of points). For distributions we don't have that problem and probably $\mathscr{L}[u_1] = \mathscr{L}[u_2] \iff u_1 = u_2.$

Comment: Regarding the definition of $\delta$; only saying 
$$\delta(x) = \begin{cases}
\infty & x = 0 \\
0 & x\neq 0 
\end{cases}$$
is clearly bogus. But when the condition $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)\,dt=1$ is added, at least the definition becomes somewhat usable. The definition $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)\,\delta(t)\,dt=f(0)$ is better and enough, though.

Comment: @ViniciusACP asking this question of a student who doesn't(shouldn't?) know how to define $\delta(2t)$ is not fair. And as I pointed out, there is still uniqueness for finite measures so the argument does not fail.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I've added the information you provided in my answer. Thanks!